# How can I push an array into an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm looking for a way to push an array into an object.

Chek this out:

```
var playlists = {
  playlist01: [],
  playlist02: [],
  playlist03: []
};
```

Now I need to push a new array, named "playlist04", but I don't know the name, I have it in a var name.

Something like this: `playlists.push($foo: []);`

Can anyone help me?

Thank you and greetings!

Comment: `playlists[variablename] = [];`

Comment: the original question didn't get the answer either; even though they are similar the problem in this one is by far more specific and it's answer is definitely "no", i.e.: 'you can not!'. You can't use the array push method on Object, and you cannot extract the name of a variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You push things into *arrays*. You add *properties* to objects. It's as simple as this:

```
playlists.playlist04 = [];
```

Or if I'm interpreting your latter code correctly, like this:

```
playlists.playlist04 = $foo;
```

*Or* if you don't know the name that you want for the property but you have that name stored in a variable, you can use bracket notation:

```
playlists[$foo] = [];
```

Comment: I think the property name is unknown in his case, might want to add code similar to Jerry's comment.

Comment: @IrkenInvader Good point. Added it.